# Bash script not taking regex pattern

Tags: regex, bash, filereader

This is my first time using bash and I want to develop a small script where, when the text file is provided as an argument, it reads the file line by line and in each line searches for words that match a certain regex pattern. If a word in a line matches the regex pattern I want the program to print the word.

shown below is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
pat = "[((?:[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*))(\\.)(png)]"
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n $line ]];do
   echo "Text read from file: $line"
   if [[ $line =~ $pat ]];
   then
        echo "line '$line'"
   else
        echo "DOES NOT MATCH BRANCH_REGEX"
   fi
done < $1
```

when I run this, the script says that:

> test2.sh: 2: test2.sh: pat: not found Text read from file: # {{
>   parameters.application_name }} Performance Test Results test2.sh: 5:
>   test2.sh: [[: not found DOES NOT MATCH BRANCH_REGEX

I cannot identify why the script is not taking the pattern

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is not valid for bash. `bash` doesn't support non-capture group and double escaping dot is also a problem. Moreover you have space around `=` that is a syntax error. You should check your script on shellcheck.net for all syntax issues.

You just need to use this regex:

```
pat='[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*\.png'
```

Comment: shellcheck.net helped but the regex is still not identifying the pattern. I have tested this regex on a python script and it works nicely. is there a way to make it compatible to bash?

Comment: Can you post sample data from input file in question so that I can test and let you know?

Answer (score 0):

fix your var declaration (remove spaces) :

```
pat="[((?:[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*))(\\.)(png)]"
```